# Proceso correcto para actualizar los paquetes de npm?

Tags: nodejs, npm

Aun estoy un poco confuso como actualizar y cual es el orden correcto.
Tengo un paquete [ncu](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) para actualizar tanto los paquetes globales como locales.

Ademas de hacer update al package.json

Pero no estoy seguro de hacerlo bien
Quisiera actualizar primero los globales, locales y update packge.json

La linea de commandos que uso son:

- ncu -n -u
- ncu -a
- npm update
- npm update -g
- npm install

Como lo haceis?

Comment: ¿Quieres actualizar todos los paquetes globales de npm?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la duda? `npm update` hace su trabajo, si quieres más detalle, ncu está perfecto.

Comment: Me gustaria saber que orden seguir para actualizar correctamente los paquetes y el package.json si primero es actualizar el package.json o los paquetes locales o globales